# String para data e subtração de dia javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso converter uma data que vem como string para `Date` e subtrair um dia dessa data.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
dataConvertida = new Date("2018-07-03")
```

Porém ao fazer a conversão, ele automaticamente desconta um dia e preciso que ele pegue exatamente a data.

Comment: Coloque o seu código, porque do jeito que está na pergunta isso não acontece...

Comment: Você tem a necessidade de receber essa data como string? Pois uma opção seria utilizar o input type Date, que já irá te retornar um valor Date

Comment: Assim ele considera o *timezone* e não traz a data correta, você pode especificar a hora e o timezone, assim: `new Date('2018-07-03T10:15:00')`

Comment: Quando você usa `new Date("2018-07-03")`, o resultado corresponde a esta data (3 de julho de 2018), à meia-noite em **UTC** (ou `2018-07-03T00:00:00Z`).
O problema é que esta mesma data em UTC pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferente em outros timezones. Por exemplo, em São Paulo, este mesmo valor corresponde a `2018-07-02T21:00-03:00` (9 da noite do dia anterior), e muitos métodos de Date usam o timezone do browser para interpretar o valor. A forma de tratar o problema vai depender do que você está fazendo com a data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estranho mesmo como isso acontece. Deve ser algo relacionado à fuso horário.

De qualquer forma, teria muito problema se em vez de `"2018-07-03"` você colocasse `"2018-07-03 00:00"`?

Dessa forma saiu correto (pelo menos aqui)

**EDIÇÃO 23/07/2019**

Sei que já faz tempo, mas enfim. Realmente o problema é o fuso horário.

Se você usa uma string com o ano, mês e dia separados com hífen, o fuso horário que o JS escolhe pra você é o Tempo Universal Coordenado (UTC), que é o fuso horário usado para calcular os demais fusos horários do mundo.

Agora se você usar barras para separar o ano, mês e dia, o fuso horário escolhido é o seu fuso horário local.

Ou seja, no seu caso seria melhor ter usado `"2018/07/03"`.

Ah, e `<input type="date">` gera valores com hífen.
Talvez essa informação seja útil pra alguém

Fonte: [Exploring Unexpected Behavior With JavaScript Date Objects](https://medium.com/@drevets/exploring-unexpected-behavior-with-javascript-date-objects-edaec2b527f9)

Answer (score -1):

Existe o método `stepDown(qnt)` que reduz a quantidade de dias do input type=date

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="date" id="data"> <!-- Pega a data --> 

<button onclick="removerUmDia()">Remover um dia</button> <!-- Botão que ativa a função, esse aqui dependerá de sua aplicação, como sua pergunta não especifica bem a utilização não tenho como ajudar mais que isso -->

<script>
function removerUmDia() {
    document.getElementById("data").stepDown(1); //Pega data e reduz 1 dia
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```